# My Python script as daemon doesn't support opening and writing outfiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, service, daemon

I finally managed to convert the process of my script in daemon, and after hours of testing I discovered that the script, converted in daemon, doesn't execute operations like:

```
out_file = open("test.txt","w")
out_file.write("")
out_file.close()
```

My script works this way:

```
class daemon: # taken here https://web.archive.org/web/20160305151936/http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/
    """A generic daemon class.

    Usage: subclass the daemon class and override the run() method."""

    def __init__(self, pidfile):
        self.pidfile = pidfile
        self.main = main

    def daemonize(self):
        """Deamonize class. UNIX double fork mechanism."""

        try: 
            pid = os.fork() 
            if pid > 0:
                # exit first parent
                sys.exit(0) 
        except OSError as err: 
            sys.stderr.write('fork #1 failed: {0}\n'.format(err))
            sys.exit(1)

        # decouple from parent environment
        os.chdir('/') 
        os.setsid() 
        os.umask(0) 

        # do second fork
        try: 
            pid = os.fork() 
            if pid > 0:

                # exit from second parent
                sys.exit(0) 
        except OSError as err: 
            sys.stderr.write('fork #2 failed: {0}\n'.format(err))
            sys.exit(1) 

        # redirect standard file descriptors
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stderr.flush()
        si = open(os.devnull, 'r')
        so = open(os.devnull, 'a+')
        se = open(os.devnull, 'a+')

        os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
        os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

        # write pidfile
        atexit.register(self.delpid)

        pid = str(os.getpid())
        with open(self.pidfile,'w+') as f:
            f.write(pid + '\n')

    def delpid(self):
        os.remove(self.pidfile)

    def start(self):
        """Start the daemon."""

        # Check for a pidfile to see if the daemon already runs
        try:
            with open(self.pidfile,'r') as pf:

                pid = int(pf.read().strip())
        except IOError:
            pid = None

        if pid:
            self.restart()

        # Start the daemon
        self.daemonize()
        self.run()

    def stop(self):
        """Stop the daemon."""

        # Get the pid from the pidfile
        try:
            with open(self.pidfile,'r') as pf:
                pid = int(pf.read().strip())
        except IOError:
            pid = None

        if not pid:
            message = "pidfile {0} does not exist. " + \
                    "Daemon not running?\n"
            sys.stderr.write(message.format(self.pidfile))
            return # not an error in a restart

        # Try killing the daemon process    
        try:
            while 1:
                os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except OSError as err:
            e = str(err.args)
            if e.find("No such process") > 0:
                if os.path.exists(self.pidfile):
                    os.remove(self.pidfile)
            else:
                print (str(err.args))
                sys.exit(1)

    def restart(self):
        """Restart the daemon."""
        self.stop()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """You should override this method when you subclass Daemon.

        It will be called after the process has been daemonized by 
        start() or restart()."""
        while True:
            self.main()

def main():
    # several and various operations

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = daemon('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
    d.start()
```

Is there a way to allow my daemon operations like opening files and writing files? And, for curiosity, why a daemon can't do I/O operations?

Comment: Does the call provides any error? If you call it as you've provided in the example it should raise `PermissionError` because you don't have rights to write in the `/` (because it's your cwd) unless you are running the code as root.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So I just need to change os.chdir("/") with the path of my home?

Comment: You don't have to even call `os.chidr()` if you are sure that the cwd will exist while your daemon is running. Preferably you should use absolute paths and using folders like `/tmp/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `os.chdir('/')` change working directory of the program to the `/`. So every relative path is relative to `/`. If you call `open("test.txt", "w")` as you've provided in the example it raises PermissionError because you don't have rights to write in the `/test.txt` unless you are running the program as the root.

You have those options:

- Always use absoluth paths
- Set cwd to directory where you have permission to write